# C2DM Registration process

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have a doubt, when we try to register for C2DM, does the registration happens in backgroud thread or in normal thread.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It is done through an Intent, now that can be blocking or unblocking based on how you develop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done through an Intent, but when google changes your registration id, you need to have a broadcast receiver to handle the new registration id. When you get the new one you need to send it to your 3rd party server to make it able to send message to the phone.
As @Jay Thakkar said, [Vogella's article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) is quite nice tutorial for understanding the c2dm.